# ASP.NET 5 support on IIS < 8

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

According to [this announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container) ASP.NET 5 discontinued helios support and embraced new hosting model that involves using HttpPlatformHandler to spawn dnx instances.
Until now it was definitely possible to run ASP.NET applications on IIS 7.5 and as far as I understand HttpPlatformHandler is for IIS 8 and 8.5. Does this mean that there will be no supported scenario for hosting ASP.NET 5 in IIS < 8 (eg. 7.5)? Are there any other alternative to HttpPlatformHandler?

Comment: as far as I understand it will work on windows server 2012 or higher. I know it won't work on server 2008, I'm not sure about 2008 R2 but I think not.

Comment: until beta-6 I was able to use it on 2008 R2 on IIS7.5

Comment: I believe Damian mentioned what platforms will be supported in the last community stand up but I can't remember exactly what he said. https://live.asp.net/

Comment: looks like you are in luck with R2 according to this thread https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364

Comment: Thanks @JoeAudette. Damian said in the very same thread that "We require IIS 7.5 as a minimum and the HttpPlatformHandler is being updated to support running on IIS 7.5".

Comment: does win server 2008 R2 not have IIS 7.5? your previous comment says it does

Comment: @JoeAudette Not quite understand where we misunderstood but pointing me to this thread answered most of my question. And yes you are right that R2 have IIS 7.5. Clue here I wanted to point is that in the future HttpPlatformHandler may be upgraded for IIS 7.5 and thus minimum requirements for ASP.NET 5 did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Damian Edwards both in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/364#issuecomment-141222391) and the [Community Standup of October 6h](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWfpAY4c3dg), HttpPlatformHandler will be available for IIS 7.5 in the future.

> Windows 7 has IIS 7.5, not IIS 7. We require IIS 7.5 as a minimum and the HttpPlatformHandler is being updated to support running on IIS 7.5

Comment: Yes that summarizes discussion I had with @JoeAudette. Are there any alternatives to HttpPlatformHandler I am missing or is this the only supported scenario?

Comment: HttpPlatformHandler is now available for IIS7.5 Installation as always through Web Platform installer.